# Get offset from locale

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I get locale info like `en-US` and `en-GB` (not timezone) and the datetime in UTC like `2016-09-23T02:00:00Z` from an API. Is it possible to use this locale to figure out the local time from the UTC datetime with offset? I have not found any `Date` api in JS that can do this directly. I have tried `toLocaleTimeString('en-US')` but that just localized the time string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ as afaik this is not supported in `Date` out of the box

Comment: I agree about using moment.js. Do *not* ever attempt to get along with timezones by yourself. Always use libraries and system utilities for that.

Comment: But they can convert time based on the timezone. The only info I am getting is the locale. I do not see how that will work.